# Having trouble with AdaptiveCard Designer accepting card payload

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I'm relatively new to this so please bare with me. I'm creating adaptive cards in PowerAutomate to post in Teams. I was previously using the built-in card designer in PowerAutomate but that's been deprecated (and consequently added weeks to my implementation as I'm severely struggling with Designer).

I've created a card in Designer, added it to my flow, and made changes as needed. I now need to troubleshoot some issues so I want to load it back into Designer. When I paste my payload back into the designer to refine it (the bottom left section), the app elements (main window) are not not always refreshing. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

I could be doing something totally incorrect but what I'm doing has been working with moderate success up until recently where it works totally randomly.

Below is the code I'm trying to populate into designer. I usually find success when I paste this into the default template leaving the Sample Data as is. At the moment, nothing is happening when I do so.

```
    {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "ExtraLarge",
            "text": "Miami Warehouse",
            "color": "Accent",
            "isSubtle": true,
            "weight": "Bolder"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "The packing slip for PO: @{outputs('Get_item')?['body/PO']} has been reviewed and processed. ",
            "wrap": true,
            "color": "Default"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Let us know when you've inventoried the shipment.",
            "wrap": true,
            "color": "Attention",
            "size": "Large",
            "weight": "Bolder"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Please update the package information below.",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                    "title": "@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/Name']}",
                    "url": "@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/Link']}",
                    "id": "linktofile"
                }
            ],
            "id": "file"
        },
        {
            "placeholder": "File Name",
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "filename",
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "label": "File Name:",
            "value": "@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/Name']}"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "PO Number",
            "id": "po",
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "label": "PO Number:",
            "value": "@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/PO']}"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "Client Name",
            "id": "client",
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "label": "Client:",
            "value": "@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/Client']}"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "Project Name",
            "id": "project",
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "label": "Project Name:",
            "value": "@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/Project']}"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "choices": @{body('Select')},
            "id": "projectmanager",
            "value": "@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/Project_x0020_Manager']}",
            "label": "Project Manager"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "spacing": "None",
                            "placeholder": "Optional",
                            "id": "trackingnumber",
                            "label": "Tracking Number:",
                            "value": "@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/Tracking_x0020_Number']}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "placeholder": "Optional",
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "spacing": "Medium",
                            "id": "carrier",
                            "label": "Carrier:",
                            "value": "@{outputs('Get_item')?['body/Carrier']}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "isMultiline": true,
            "id": "notes",
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "label": "Description:",
            "placeholder": "",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "SHIPMENT INVENTORIED",
                    "id": "inventoried"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to JSON that you have provided is not valid
[image]

As you can see here it is showing error at `Input.ChoiceSet` if I make `@{body('Select'}` as string i.e. `"@{body('Select'}"` it doesn't give any error and I can see the preview of it.

This error you will get in Adaptive Card designer itself if you look closely, also there are multiple JSON validator available on web. Such as https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thank you so much. Interestingly, my workflow is running just fine without showing an error for this.

Comment: Oh That's weird, but sounds good if it is workig

Comment: I've also discovered that adding the quotes around `@{body('Select'}` kills the flow.

Comment: I doubt, but I can see after that too you have other as well in double quotes.